# How do I create a symmetrical blob?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new to illustrator, sorry if this is basic. How do I create those weird blobs from Animal Crossing? I am  struggling to make them symmetrical horizontally and vertically.

[image: blob]
[image: blob2]
[image: blob3]

Also, I would like to draw this button, but I don't know how to make a smooth transition from a curve to a perfectly horizontal line. Note that the sides are not perfectly circular.

[image: button]

Comment: Is it really a blob if it’s symmetrical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get those items which look distorted ellipses is to start from a circular path. In Illustrator you draw an ellipse holding Shift and it's the cleanest circle-like path that Illustrator makes. In other programs there is a circle tool. Its product must be converted to path. The next example is in Inkscape:

[image]

In the left there's the usual circular 4-node path. In the right the path is rotated 45 degrees to have the other possible horizontally and vertically symmetric node constellation

It can be distorted easily without making it an ellipse, but still keeping it symmetric:

[image]

In the left 2 nodes (blue) are selected and moved to the right by pressing a few tics with the right arrow key. In the right the result is scaled to a little lower.

In Illustrator you must apply Object -> Transform -> Rotate -> 45 degrees to get the perfect rotation. Reset the bounding box, too for easy horizontal and vertical scaling after the rotation and node editing.

The effect of the arrow key must be set in the program preferences.

If you want also straight parts between the curved corners you can make with the pen a quarter of the shape. It looks smooth if the endpoint nodes have horizontal and vertical handles and the intermediate nodes have symmetric handles. An example:

[image]

One quarter is drawn and 3 flipped copies are made. They snap together perfectly and can be joined to one path without hitches. Drawing the handles on the fly with the pen needs some practicing. In Illustrator one holds shift to get perfecly vertical or horizontal handles. Ctrl-key does the same in Inkscape. Intermediate nodes get symmetric handles by default but they can also be converted.

To keep it simple make only 1...2 intermediate nodes when you draw the 1st quarter. This one got only a single intermediate node and it is aligned with the right end node to the same elevation for perfect straightness.

Answer (score 4):

You can draw a rectangle and use the corner widgets to adjust (round) all corners or only selected corners.

First make sure you have Show Corner Widgets checked in the View Menu. Then in my version of Illustrator (2023) the corner widgets are there and you do not have to change tools to manipulate them. This will round all of the corners equally (until they form a semi circle).

To round only certain corners use the Direct Selection Tool (White Arrow) and select one or more corners you want to round. Use their corner widget to adjust.

You can also adjust one or more corners using the Transform Panel (Window> Transform). At the bottom you can numerically adjust all or each corner radius numerically. Clicking the chain icon will toggle between adjusting them all or individually.

[image]

Comment: Cool animation! But I think OP is looking for a more organic corner shapes than perfect arcs.